# Future type recursive function not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make my own image picker. I don't like the UI of [`multi_image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker).

My code does not return the desired output on first function call.
But when I press the `IconButton` again, it works fine and returns the desired output.

The code looks like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  List<String> extensionList = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.bmp'];
  Set<String> pathsOfDirectory = Set<String>();
  Set<String> allFilePaths = Set<String>();
  List<FileSystemEntity> file = List();

  Future<void> recursion(String mainDirectoryPath) async {
    file = [];
    file = Directory(mainDirectoryPath).listSync();
    String thisFilePath;
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
      thisFilePath = file[i].path;
      bool isFile = await FileSystemEntity.isFile(thisFilePath);
      if (isFile && extensionList.contains(path.extension(thisFilePath))) {
        String dirname = path.dirname(thisFilePath);
        if (!path.basename(dirname).endsWith('/0')) {
          pathsOfDirectory.add(dirname);
        }
        allFilePaths.add(thisFilePath);
      } else {
        if (!(thisFilePath.contains('Android') ||
                thisFilePath.contains('.') ||
                thisFilePath.contains('WhatsApp Images/Sent')) &&
            Directory(thisFilePath).existsSync()) {
          recursion(thisFilePath);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  height: 40,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        iconSize: 28,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.calculate),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Directory directory =
                              await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                          String mainDirectoryPath =
                              directory.parent.parent.parent.parent.path;
                          print(mainDirectoryPath);
                          await recursion(mainDirectoryPath);
                          print(pathsOfDirectory);
                          print(allFilePaths.length);
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The outputs are:

```
I/flutter (25730): /storage/emulated/0
I/flutter (25730): {/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/PrettyMakeupExample, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/DocScanner, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/InstaMocks, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera, /storage/emulated/0/documents/Kaagaz/images, /storage/emulated/0/documents/New folder/Hh, /storage/emulated/0/Download}
I/flutter (25730): 42
I/flutter (25730): /storage/emulated/0
I/flutter (25730): {/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/PrettyMakeupExample, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/DocScanner, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/InstaMocks, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera, /storage/emulated/0/documents/Kaagaz/images, /storage/emulated/0/documents/New folder/Hh, /storage/emulated/0/Download, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images, /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents}
I/flutter (25730): 658
```

It happens when I navigate from HomePage to this page. But after coming to `TestScreen`, if I do hot reload and then press the `IconButton` for the first time it will show correct results. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not `await`-ing your `recursive` call in your `recursion` function.